# Opencv - Triangulation origin with stereo system

Tags: opencv, triangulation, stereo-3d

I m using a stereo system and so i m trying to get world coordinates of some points. I can do it with specific calibration for each camera and then i calculate rotation matrix and translation vector. And finally i triangulate but i m not sure of the origin of the world coordinates.

As you can see on my figure, values correspond to depth value but they shoud be close of 400 as it is flat. So i suppose that the origin is the left camera that s why it variates...

[image]

A piece of my code with my projective arrays and triangulate function :

```
#C1 and C2 are the cameras matrix (left and rig)
#R_0 and T_0 are the transformation between cameras
#Coord1 and Coord2 are the correspondant coordinates of left and right respectively
P1 = np.dot(C1,np.hstack((np.identity(3),np.zeros((3,1))))) 

P2 =np.dot(C2,np.hstack(((R_0),T_0)))

for i in range(Coord1.shape[0])
    z = cv2.triangulatePoints(P1, P2, Coord1[i,],Coord2[i,])
```

My cameras present an angle, the Z axis direction (direction of the depth) is not normal to my surface. And i want the depth from the baseline direction. So i have to rotate my points?

[image]

Comment: using identity and zero translation means that everything is computed according to C1 coordinate system and C1 sensor is the origin.

Comment: Ok but for the triangulation i have to do that hasnt it? If i want to "transport" depth in a landmark with a normal to my surface how to do that?  it is a "rigid body motion" transform? thanks for help ;)

Comment: you can form your P1 and P2 using C1 rotation matrix in world coordinate system and C1 translation in world coordinate system. then form P2 using the same idea. this way triangluatePoints will give 4D points in world coordinate system. If you want this, I can provide an answer but I only did it in C++ but you will get the idea

Comment: Sorry i was eating... I work on python but to see clearly how to do that it will be helpfull :) And i have a little question...is it an obligation to rectify? is it not necessary if i use somme optical flow method isnt it? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code, points4DNorm will contains the 3D points in world coordinates. I didn't use rectify at all, I just used a few 2d/3d point pairs and then solvePnPRansac on these pairs.

```
// rotMat1, rotMat2,tvec1 and tvec2 are retrieved from solvePnPRansac and Rodrigues
        Mat points4D;
        rotMat1.copyTo(myCam1.ProjectionMat(Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));
        tvec1.copyTo(myCam1.ProjectionMat(Rect(3, 0, 1, 3)));

        rotMat2.copyTo(myCam2.ProjectionMat(Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));
        tvec2.copyTo(myCam2.ProjectionMat(Rect(3, 0, 1, 3)));

        myCam1.ProjectionMat = myCam1.NewCameraMat* myCam1.ProjectionMat;
        myCam2.ProjectionMat = myCam2.NewCameraMat* myCam2.ProjectionMat;
        triangulatePoints(myCam1.ProjectionMat, myCam2.ProjectionMat, balls12d, balls22d, points4D);
        Mat points4DNorm;
      for (int k = 0; k < points4D.cols;k++)
      {
        points4D.at<float>(0, k) = (points4D.at<float>(0, k) / points4D.at<float>(3, k))/304.8;
        points4D.at<float>(1, k) = (points4D.at<float>(1, k) / points4D.at<float>(3, k)) / 304.8;
        points4D.at<float>(2, k) = (points4D.at<float>(2, k) / points4D.at<float>(3, k)) / 304.8;
        points4D.at<float>(3, k) = (points4D.at<float>(3, k) / points4D.at<float>(3, k)) / 304.8;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << points4D.at<float>(0, k) << "," << points4D.at<float>(1, k) << "," << points4D.at<float>(2, k) << std::endl;
       }
```